# JDK 9 SIGSEGV Fatal Error

Tags: javafx, eclipse-plugin, java-9, javafx-9

Running eclipse plugin with a WebView component ends with SIGSEGV error, which happens to be an ancient bug as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101142/java-fatal-error-sigsegv).

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000013a06a254, pid=23881, tid=775
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (9.0+11) (build 9.0.4+11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (9.0.4+11, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, bsd-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjfxwebkit.dylib+0x5ff254]  WebCore::FrameTree::top() const+0x4
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/hs_err_pid23881.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Is there any new configuration or vm parameter we are missing specific to Java 9 ?

Comment: is this JavaFX + webkit? Do you have a test case for a bug report?

Comment: This is an internal Eclipse plugin we are trying to upgrade from Elipse 3x to Java fx. The problem arises from a recursive function, which should be cought by some exception like stackoverflow, etc. But we get the SIGSEGV, and I know no way of recovering from.  Thanks.